# Search records in muliple tables from a single search form

Tags: laravel

I have these two tables named `posts` and `events`, both tables are not related at all and I want users to be able to search from these two tables using a single search form. Here is what I've got so far :

```
public function search(Request $request) {
   $input = trim($request->input('q'));
   $keywords = strtolower($input);
   $keywordArr = explode(' ', $keywords);

   if (!empty($keywords)) {

      foreach($keywordArr as $key) {
          $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->get();
          $events = Event::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->get();
      }
      return view('search/results', compact('posts','events','keywords'));
   }
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

That method doesn't work as expected. If both tables has records that match users keywords this method will only return result from `events` table. How do I solve this ? that's all and thanks!

Comment: Try Laravel Searchable https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

Comment: I don't want to use any package if possible @HasibMahmud

Comment: `$posts, $events` need to be array if you put them inside `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using laravel searchable package,try this method.

Controller file.

```
public function searchFunction(Request $request)
    {
       $result= ModelName::search($search)->get();
    }
```

Model file.

```
class   ModelName extends Model
{
    use SearchableTrait;

    protected $searchable = [
        'columns' => [
            'posts.title' => 10,
            'events.title' => 9
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Alright, seems like the easiest way is to use this package. I tried it and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Laravel Scout: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout

It would help making your search much faster and way more relevant compare to a `LIKE` query with MySQL.